# How to minimize given functional

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-programming

I confronted the next problem: we have certain values $\psi_1, \psi_2, \psi_3$ in 3 points $x_1, x_2, x_3$, also we have a general functtion with 2 undefined coefficients ($A,x_0$): $$\psi=A\exp(x-x_0)$$ We need to find this coefficients using the next functional: $$\Phi = (\psi(x_1)-\psi_1)^2+(\psi(x_2)-\psi_2)^2+(\psi(x_3)-\psi_3)^2)$$
**The main goal** is to compose the $\psi$ function which would be the best approximization for the given 3 values.

As I undestand for finding $\psi(x_1), \psi(x_2), \psi (x_3)$ we need to minimize the functional $\Phi$. Can you provide us the best approach for such minimization or some other way for finding the coefficients of general function $\psi$. The photo with illustration is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need and you can only determine one coefficient. The other can be chosen arbitrary.

$y=A\cdot e^{x_i-x_0}=A\cdot e^{x_i}\cdot e^{-x_0}$

$A$ and $e^{-x_0}$ are constants. The product can be replaced by $e^k$. This means that $A$ and $e^{-x_0}$ cannot be definetely specified. Now we have

$y=e^k\cdot e^{x_i}$ with $k\neq 0$

Taking logs

$ln(y)=k+x_i$

Thus the sum of squared residuals is

$ssr=\sum_{i=1}^n \left( ln(y_i)-k-x_i\right)^2 $

the derivative w.r.t k is

$\frac{\partial \ ssr}{\partial k}=\sum_{i=1}^n 2\cdot \left( ln(y_i)-k-x_i\right)\cdot (-1)=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n  ln(y_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n k- \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n  ln(y_i)-n\cdot k- n\cdot \overline x=0$

$n\cdot k=\sum_{i=1}^n  ln(y_i)-n\cdot \overline x$

$k=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n  ln(y_i)}{n}-\overline x$

This k is $A\cdot e^{-x_0}$. As I said one of this factors can be chosen arbitrary.

For example, if $k= 2$ then $x_0$ can be $-ln(2)$. Then the equation is

$2=A\cdot e^{-(-ln(2))}=A\cdot e^{ln(2)}=A\cdot 2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad A=1 $

Comment: thx, it helped a lot, I made my own reserch on the theme and now I am pretty confident of how to do this

Answer (score 0):

So you have $\Phi(x_0, A)$, it is a smooth function and you need to find its minimum. Which methods do you know that would help you to do that? For example, taking derivative and equating it to zero?

Comment: It is the first time I do it, so could you please give the simplest method, as taking derivative and equating it to zero. With your explanation, please. The initial problem is that we have results of experiment and we need to approximate it with the function of $\psi$-type and $A$ , $x_0$ are the coefficients, which are constansts.